# Stack Overflow on serialport

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

My pseudo code is this...

the GetData_1() sends a request to serial Port, after receiving the Reply,  another request is send by GetData_2(). After receiving the response of second request all the received data is together inserted into the database. And then the GetData_1() is called again to continue this process recursively...

But........
Am getting an error  of stack over flow...
please help...

```
 GetDat_1()

{

//Send a request To SerialPort

//wait a 500 ms.

// read The response and insert it into an array...

GetData_2();
}

GetData_2()
{
// Send a request to SerialPort

// Wait a 500 ms.

// Read The response and insert it into another array

InsertAllData();

GetData_1();
}

InsertAllData()
{
// insert all data into the database
}
```

Comment: The code is just broken, you call GetData1 from GetData2.  Which calls GetData2 which calls GetData1.  Which calls GetData2... *Kaboom!*

Comment: @HansPassant it's questions like these that really give this site it's name :)

Comment: +1 for getting a StackOverFlowException and asking about it on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the repeated calls never return and the call stack just keeps on growing resulting in a [StackOverFlowException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) sooner or later, most likely sooner.

Instead, unroll into an iterative way of coding.

```
while (!done)
    // GetDat_1 is inlined here
    // Send a request To SerialPort 
    // wait a 500 ms.
    // read The response and insert it into an array...

    // GetData_2 is inlined here
    // Send a request to SerialPort
    // Wait a 500 ms.   
    // Read The response and insert it into another array

    InsertAllData();
}
```

Comment: thank my by acepting the answer. There is a green outlined checkbox to the left of this answer. Please click it if my answer helped you. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

GetData_1() calls GetData_2() which calls GetData_1() which calls GetData_2()... so on and so on forever until you hit your stack overflow.

You'll need to redesign your methods to work in another way

Maybe using a loop of some type in this scenario would be better.

Answer (score 1):

`GetData_1()`  and `GetData_2()` calling each one so this is a dead loop. And since any method call "record" some data in the stack of a thread (method parameters, etc) such infinitive calls causes stack overflow because stack is not unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with serial ports. This can be easily reproduced by just

```
Getdata_1()
{
Getdata_2();
}

Getdata_2()
{
GetData_1();
}
```

and nothing else.

There is no easy solution. You need to read up about recursion and adjust your algorithm accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this sample code, removing `GetData1` and `GetData2` methods

```
while (true)
{
   //Send a request To SerialPort  
   //wait a 500 ms.  
   // read The response and insert it into an array... 

   // Send a request to SerialPort  
   // Wait a 500 ms.  
   // Read The response and insert it into another array 

   InsertAllData();

   if (/*set true if i want to end the loop*/)
      break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
while(!done)
{
    //Send request
    GetData_1();
    //Send request
    GetData_2();
    InsertAllData();
}
```

Although I would set up an interrupt to collect the data from the serial port.